# Rails - Fetch results on the basis of number of params in query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, query-string

I am working on an events application where i want to filter events depending on the 3 parameters **location or starts_at or ends_at** in the query string. There can be any one, two or all the parameters in the query string. In i use **if-else** statement i need to make 6 cases which will make my code clumsy. Rather i am thinking to implement something this way:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    unless params.empty?
      unless params[:location].nil?
        @events = Event.where("location = ?", params[:location])       
      end

       unless params[:starts_at].nil?
         unless @events.empty?
           @events = @events.where("start_date = ?", params[:start_date])      
         else
           @events = Event.where("Date(starts_at) = Date(?)", params[:starts_at])
         end
       end
       unless params[:ends_at].nil?
         unless @events.empty?
           @events = @events.where("end_date = ?", params[:end_date])      
         else
           @events = Event.where("Date(ends_at) = Date(?)", params[:ends_at])
         end
       end
    end
  end
end
```

But this code doesnt work since **where** query doen not work on an array. Can someone suggest me some solution for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass your `params` hash directly to `where`, and it will form the correct SQL based on the keys and values of that hash:

```
Event.where(params)
```

An example in the console:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > puts Example.where(:location => 'here', :started_at => '2012-08-13').to_sql
SELECT "examples".* FROM "examples"  WHERE "examples"."location" = 'here' AND "examples"."started_at" = '2012-08-13'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
  def index
    unless params.empty?
      where_array, arr = [], []
      if params[:location]
        where_array << "location = ?"
        arr << params[:location]
      end
      if params[:starts_at]
        where_array << "start_date = ?"
        arr << params[:starts_at]
      end
      if params[:ends_at]
        where_array << "end_date = ?"
        arr << params[:ends_at]
      end
       @events = arr.blank? ? [] : Event.where([where_array.join(" AND "), *arr])
    end
  end
```